# Jhipster PrimeNG Scheduler component

Tags: typescript, components, jhipster, primeng

I add PrimeNG Scheduler commponent to Jhipster, and had this error.

> ERROR TypeError: this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function

If i understand right, I need to import some js file. In which file can I import it ? (angular-cli.json doesn't work)

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a JHipster example app using primeng autocomplete https://github.com/gmarziou/jhipster-ui-libs/tree/primeng, check the last commit to see what I did  to make it work:  https://github.com/gmarziou/jhipster-ui-libs/commit/d27f480aedb4733563c04588c4fef4a04dcf8813

Answer (score 0):

> angular-cli.json doesn't work

Yes it does.

First install fullcalendar :

```
npm install fullcalendar --save
```

Then in your `angular-cli.json` file :

```
"styles": [
         ...
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        ...
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"
      ],
...
```

Comment: No, it doesnt. I use yarn, not npm.

Comment: Try `yarn add fullcalendar`

Comment: I do what, but nothing was changed

Comment: Do you have `fullcalendar` directory in your `node_modules` ?

Comment: Yes, I have it. Also I import css file from directory to vendor.css

Comment: Do you still have the issue if you import fullcalendar directly in your `index.html` file ? `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, I still have it.

Comment: JHipster webpack configuration does not rely on angular-cli, so it does not help editing angular-cli.json for dependencies.